# Unstable theories in which every formula is stably embedded

Tags: logic, model-theory

Fix an arbitrary first-order theory $T$ and a monster model $\mathfrak{U}\models T$. Recall that a $\emptyset$-definable subset $D\subseteq\mathfrak{U}$ is said to be "stably embedded" if, for any formula $\varphi(\overline{v},\overline{c})$ with arbitrary parameters, the set $\varphi(D,\overline{c})$ is $D$-definable. We say also that a single-variable formula $\theta(v)$ without parameters is stably embedded if $\theta(\mathfrak{U})\subseteq\mathfrak{U}$ is stably embedded. Now, if $T$ is stable, then every formula is stably embedded. (See e.g. Tent and Ziegler, Corollary 8.3.3.) What can we say in the opposite direction? The question I want to ask is this:

> If every formula of $T$ is stably embedded, then is $T$ stable?

However, there are easy counterexamples to this. For instance, if $T=\text{DLO}$, then any two elements of $\mathfrak{U}$ have the same type over $\emptyset$, and hence the only $\emptyset$-definable sets are $\emptyset$ and $\mathfrak{U}$, each of which is clearly stably embedded. But $\text{DLO}$ is not stable. So, certainly there are unstable theories in which every formula is stably embedded. However, I find this example slightly unsatisfying, since the only $\emptyset$-definable subsets are trivial. Unfortunately, things don't get any better if we demand that $T$ has non-trivial $\emptyset$-definable subsets, since (for example) adding a constant symbol to the $\text{DLO}$ example will not change anything. So, I'm not exactly sure what the right formulation of my question is. Very vaguely:

> Is there a "natural" property $P$ of $\emptyset$-definable subsets of a theory such that, if $T$ has at least one $\emptyset$-definable subset satisfying property $P$, and every formula of $T$ is stably embedded, then $T$ is stable?

Apologies for the enormous vagueness of this question, and please feel free to close if it is too imprecise. But I would be interested in any insight anyone might have!

Answer (score 2):

Certainly $P$ should be stable and stably embedded. It must also be in some sense "large" for otherwise you can take the disjoint union of a stable theory and an arbitrary theory. One way to make this precise is this: you have a theory $T$ and a distniguished definable set $P$ which is stable and stably embedded such that $M$ and $P(M)$ have the same cardinality for every model $M$. Then does it follow that $T$ is stable? I suspect the answer is yes but I'm not sure.

Comment: thank you, this is an interesting idea... I'll have a think about it!

Comment: But ACVF is not stable, M, k(M) have the same cardinality for certain maximal ideal m, and k(M) as an ACF is stable and stably embedded by QE in the three-sorted language.